# How to export data in Oracle database into CSV file with UTF-8 format?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, csv, encoding

I have an CSV file with `WE8ISO8859P1` encoding generated from Oracle Stored Procedure. Is there any script line to define the output of `CSV` file in UTF-8 encoded format?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE export_main(dir VARCHAR2, file_name VARCHAR2)
  IS
 select_stmt VARCHAR2(100) := 'SELECT MTYPE || '','' || MNO FROM MAIN';
    cur INTEGER;
    file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    row_value VARCHAR2(4000);
    ret INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    -- Open a cursor for the specified SELECT statement
    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, select_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);

    -- All columns were concatenated into single value in SELECT
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cur, 1, row_value, 4000);

    -- Open the file for writing
    --file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);
file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(UPPER(dir), file_name, 'w', 32767);
    -- Export rows one by one
    LOOP
       ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cur);
       EXIT WHEN ret = 0;

       -- Get the value
       row_value := NULL;
       DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur, 1, row_value);

       -- Write the row to the file
      -- UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, row_value);
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR(file, TO_NCHAR(row_value));
    END LOOP;

     UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file);
     DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

    EXCEPTION WHEN NOT_LOGGED_ON THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('A program issues a database call without being connected to Oracle.');
  END;
```

Oracle database is encoded with `WE8ISO8859P1` and postgres DB is encoded with `UTF-8`

I need to import CSV file into Postgres DB table using stored procedure where in postgres by default encoding is `UTF-8`

Comment: Is your DB really `ASCII` (i.e. `US7ASCII`)? ASCII I s strict subset of UTF-8, so **each** ASCII File (or string) is identical to its UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: Oracle NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8ISO8859P1

Answer (score 1):

[UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/UTL_FILE.htm#ARPLS70946)

> This procedure writes the text string stored in the buffer parameter
>   to the open file identified by the file handle. With this function,
>   you can write a text file in Unicode instead of in the database
>   character set.

So you could try something like this:

```
-- Write the row to the file
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR(file, TO_NCHAR(row_value));
```

Comment: Error
Procedure execution failed
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 745

Comment: @Ajay Takur Did you replace `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` with `UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR`?

Comment: Yes i did replaced please check the above changed script